# Applescript: How to get System Events to include subfolders in results?

Tags: finder, applescript, folders

This is a script that selects a random pdf from a particular folder and reveals it in Finder. But it only selects a pdf from the top level of the folder. How can I get it to look into subfolders as well?

```
set j to "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Documents:pdfs"

tell application "System Events"
    set all_pdfs to path of every file in folder j whose visible = true and name extension is "pdf"
end tell

set random_pdf to some item of all_pdfs

# uses an existing window or makes a new window with your default settings
tell application "Finder"
    reopen # makes a new window if there are no open windows
    activate
    set target of window 1 to random_pdf
end tell
```

note: I'm using System Events because it's much faster than Finder.

Comment: **System Events** doesn’t have anything like that, so you would need to traverse the folder hierarchy or use a shell utility such as `find`.

Comment: @red_menace Are you saying that System Events cannot be used to select files inside subfolders? That's false. System Events can deal with "folders of the_folder". However, I don't know how to adapt the "folders of the_folder" construct to my purpose. Source: https://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=195609

Comment: No, I was just saying that **System Events** doesn’t have anything to look into all the subfolders (such as the **Finder**'s `entire contents`) without you explicitly doing it, as mentioned in my previous comment and your linked topic.

Comment: Assuming that your drive is indexed, you may find it faster to use mdfind, with the 'do shell' part looking like this: `do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & "~/Documents/" & " -name '.pdf'"`. Offhand, I think the 'as alias' may be redundant.

Comment: _"note: I'm using System Events because it's much faster than Finder"_ You're correct to do so, it's everyone else who defaults to using _Findar_ that should be ones leaving a footnote: _"note: I am using Finder because everyone else does it."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is an alternative method:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set pdfFilesList to paragraphs of (do shell script "find ~/Documents -type f -iname '*.pdf'")

set pdfFile to POSIX file (some item of pdfFilesList) as alias

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    reveal pdfFile
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, and works quickly. I shouldn't have specified System Events in my title. Alternative ways are fine.

Comment: This solution does not filter the `whose visible is true` property as requested in the OP

Comment: @wch1zpink, RE: "This solution does not filter the `whose visible is true property` as requested in the OP" --  Even though the _code_ in the OP was doing that, nonetheless, there was no explicit request made in the _text_ of the _question_ that it must filter on visible **PFD** _files_. BTW It also didn't contain `pdfs` in the _path_ portion of the `find` _command_. Note that it's was clearly and plainly stated "_Example_ **AppleScript** _code_:", meaning it's just that, an _example_!

Comment: @wch1zpink, I don't actually know the significance of `whose visible is true`. I was just copy-pasting code found by googling. In my use case it probably doesn't matter. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Runty, RE: "I don't actually know the significance of `whose visible is true`" --  It forces the inclusion of only _visible files_, or excludes _hidden files_, which in your use case I doubt you have any hidden **PDF** _files_ and as such wouldn't be necessary and why I did not include it in my _example_ **AppleScript** _code_.

Comment: @user3439894, is it okay to do a follow-up here? I'm trying to get it to work with gnu locate `glocate` but I'm getting the error `error "Can’t get some item of {}." number -1728 from some item of {}`. The only difference that I can see in the output is that `glocate` does not include the beginning slash of the pathnames. How can I get this script to work with glocate instead of find?

Comment: @Runty, RE: "is it okay to do a follow-up here?" -- It depends on the question and in this particular use case It's better that you post a new question, showing what you are working with and how it's not doing as you expect/want, etc.  Also note that `glocate` is not a default part of **macOS**, so you should include appropriate information about it as well. Thanks.

Comment: Got `glocate` to work by specifying location of my locatedb: `do shell script "[[ -f \"$HOME/locatedb\" ]] && export LOCATE_PATH=\"$HOME/locatedb\"; /usr/local/bin/glocate -i '*my_filter*'`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you.

```
property mainFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Documents:pdfs"

set theFiles to paragraphs of (do shell script "find " & ¬
    quoted form of POSIX path of mainFolder & " -iname '*.pdf'")
set visiblePDFs to {}

tell application "System Events"
    repeat with thisFile in theFiles
        if visible of file thisFile then set end of visiblePDFs to contents of thisFile
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    reveal some item of visiblePDFs as POSIX file
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works, although it's pretty slow with 10 thousand pdfs. (I shouldn't have specified System Events -- alternatives are fine.)